# ASP.NET DataGrid - Getting "Select" to work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been looking online for a way to get the "Select" button to work. I've got a Member table that can get data, but I can't select a single member and get more information about him from the database. ie. I want the database to change "view" and show me that members details.

All the online guides I've found online only talk about the "Edit" and "Delete" key.

A picture showing my database in VS10.
http://i46.tinypic.com/szznmq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *get the "Select" button to work* - After adding the SelectCommand, you should subscribe to the `SelectedIndexChanged` command of the grid and do whatever you want in that event.

For instance:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        // Do whatever you want
        row.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me alot. I added the "OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" to my .asp file and the code you specified to my .cs and it worked :)